# How to get text from a inputstream of google drive HttpResponse?

Tags: inputstream, google-drive-api, httpresponse, apache-tika

I am trying to get the data from inputstream. I am getting it with gdrive HttpResponse. Plz check it in code below.

```
HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(
                         new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();

BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(resp.getContent()));
System.out.println("Shorten Response: ");
for (String line = output.readLine(); line != null; line = output.readLine()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

I am reading .doc file and i am getting the output like a decoded form:-

��ࡱ�  � & ]� �    �

How to read it as string? plz help me to resolve this.

Comment: What you get is propably the binary data of a Google drive document in a binary format (ods, doc). You may save to a local file and then convert to plain text.

Comment: You may also be getting encrypted string...

Comment: How to get content using solr tike with this binary data? is it possible to get it with solr tike /update/extract/.